# Timer for python functions

Tags: python, function, timer, mouse

I'm trying to do an automatic mouse clicker. My main issue now is how to do a timer for each function, for example, function 1 works for about 15 minutes, then function 2 after the 15 minutes starts to work just one time, then comeback to function 1. And i want to function4 Works independente from the others, i want it to click everytime even if the function 1 is running ( im not sure if this is possible) here is my code:

```
    import pyautogui, sys
pyautogui.size()
(1280, 800)

def function1():
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=619, y=266) 
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 3.9
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=617, y=475)

def function2():
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=624, y=347)
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 5.0
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=615, y=431)
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 5.0
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=315, y=483)
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 5.0
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=616, y=390)


def function3 ():
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=617, y=522)
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 5.0


def function4():
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=1257, y=432)
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: Have u tried importing time, theN use time.sleep(x) x being the number of seconds to delay.

Comment: That means i should make it without functions, right?

Comment: But, well if i do that, then the function 1 run the code, then sleep for 15 ( do nothing ) and then function2 start, and that's not the point. I want to function1 run as a loop for 15 minutes then run  one time function 2 and return to function1 as a loop...

Comment: Could you add the main part of source code where all functions (1 to 4) are called ? I don't think that you can call `function4()` independently from others running functions.

Comment: splash()
storm()
defensive()
pick()

Comment: that come after the code i have post, but the main thing is how i can settimer for a function, just like authotkey Settimer ( functionname = time ) and function run when reach that time... i look at the documents of python but i can't find something similar

Comment: For the `function4()` to work independently from other functions, did you try `pyautogui.click(button='left', x=1257, y=432, interval=<Delay>)` with <Delay> equal to the period ? (from **["PyAutoGUI - Mouse Control Functions"](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)**).

Comment: Ill try! Btw any idea to set timers for each function?

Comment: Already try and don't work, well ill resume once again, im loking to set a timer for each function be called... thats the point...

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not easy to manage multiple functions with wait independently without introducing a signal and multi-thread, here is another way to manage multiple `click()` functions with the `PyAutoGUI` library.

> The solution is a multi-sequencer class (called `class TimerExec`).

**Step 1** - Use a `class TimerSeq` to store sequencer parameters

> Only the constructor is needed

```
class TimerSeq:
    def __init__(self, iseq, tseq, bexe, bloop):    
        self.iseq = iseq
        self.tseq = tseq
        self.bexe = bexe
        self.bloop = bloop
```

**Step 2** - Create a `class TimerExec` to manage a list of sequencers

> The constructor create an empty list

```
class TimerExec:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [ ]
        self.stop = True
        self.chrono = -1
        self.delay = -1
```

> A simple floating-point seconds value to int milliseconds

```
#
# convert float seconds to milliseconds
def tomilli(self, fsec):
    return int(round(fsec * 1000))
```

> Add a new sequencer in the list

```
#
# append new sequences to the list
def append(self, func, loop=False):
    self.list.append([func, TimerSeq(-1, -1, False, loop)])
    print('list:',self.list)
```

> Verify if the sequencer is complete or restart when loop

```
#
# check end of sequence or restart
def nextcheck(self, seq):
    if seq[1].iseq >= len(seq[0]):
        if seq[1].bloop:
            seq[1].iseq = 0 # restart
        return True
    return False
```

> Compute parameters for the next sequence in the current sequencer

```
#
# switch to the next sequence
def nextstep(self, seq):
    if seq[1].iseq >= len(seq[0]):
        return True
    seq[1].iseq = seq[1].iseq+1
    seq[1].tseq = self.tomilli(time.time())
    seq[1].bexe = False
    return False
```

> Manage the current sequencer and execute the current function then
>   delay the next sequence

```
#
# explore sequence and execute when  
def exestep(self, seq):
    bseq = False
    if seq[1].tseq < 0:
        bseq = self.nextstep(seq)
    else:
        bseq = self.nextcheck(seq)
    if bseq:
        return True
    pseq = seq[0][seq[1].iseq]
    tnow = self.tomilli(time.time())
    tdel = self.tomilli(pseq[0])
    if seq[1].bexe == False:
        print('execute(%d):'% (tnow-self.chrono),pseq)
        # execute the selected function
        pseq[1](pseq[2],pseq[3],pseq[4])
        seq[1].bexe = True 
    tseq = seq[1].tseq
    if tnow > (tseq+tdel):
        bseq = self.nextstep(seq)
    return bseq
```

> Main loop function to explore all sequencers until complete or
>   max_delay

```
#
# loop to execute all sequences with max_delay (s)
def execute(self, max_delay):
    print('start:',time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
    self.stop = False
    self.delay = self.tomilli(max_delay)
    self.chrono = self.tomilli(time.time())
    while self.stop == False:
        tnow = self.tomilli(time.time())
        #if tnow > (self.chrono + self.delay):
        #    break
        bstop = True
        for seq in self.list:
            bseq = self.exestep(seq)
            bstop = bstop & bseq
        if bstop == True:
            self.stop = True    
    print('stop:',time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()),
          ((tnow-self.chrono)/1000.0))
```

**Step 3** - declare your sequencer based to your declared function

For function1(), use a 2 steps sequencer:

```
def function1():
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=619, y=266) 
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 3.9
        pyautogui.click(button='left', x=617, y=475)
```

The sequencer is:

```
fct1 = [
  # pyautogui.click(button='left', x=619, y=266) 
  [ 3.9, pyautogui.click, 'left', 619, 266 ],
  # pyautogui.click(button='left', x=617, y=475)
  [ 0.0, pyautogui.click, 'left', 617, 475 ]
]
```

**Step 4** - Create TimerExec object, add sequencer then execute.

> The duration is limited to 13.6 seconds maximum

```
tSeq = TimerExec()
tSeq.append(fct1)
tSeq.execute(13.6)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, a lit bit more complicated then i have imagine. I'll try. Thank you once again.